# Django static tag on css(style-bg-image)

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to make a webpage in django everything works well

{% static 'website/img/core-img/s1.png' %}

but when I try to do static style="background-image: url({% static 'website/img/bg-img/1.jpg'%});

it gives me errors:
[on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtv5B.png)

Comment: Does the template load okay? Is this just your IDE showing errors?

Comment: >> it gives me those stupid errors.
which errors? django template tag  error or error in browser "file not exists"?

Comment: errors are not stupid, you can't put image inside `<div (*img)></div>`, it supposed to be like this `<div style="backgroundcolor:green;">(*img)</div>`

Comment: ohhh yep it look like it's just IDE.
thanks @Iain Shelvington

Comment: @oruchkin why not? look at this
<div class="breadcumb-area bg-img bg-gradient-overlay" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/12.jpg);"> </div> and it works good
also with djnago tags
<div class="welcome-welcome-slide bg-img bg-gradient-overlay jarallax" style="background-image: url({% static 'website/img/bg-img/1.jpg' %});">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE isn't configured to work with Django markup language, try add django plugin:

Search `django` on plugins and hit install.
[image: screenshot showing vscode plugins and install button to django plugin]

Then, on your file click inside detected language (HTML) and change to Django HTML
[image: language selector]
[image: language list]